# How do I add a label to identical cards in Wallet?

Tags: iphone, wallet

I have 2 identical transit cards in my Apple wallet. One is for personal use. The other for business use.

Unfortunately, other than the position in the stack and the amount of money on the card there is no way to tell which card is which.

It seems like there has to be some way to add a label to the cards, ideally at the top so I can know which one to select.

How can one add a label to cards in Apple wallet?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be possible at present. (See Apple discussions [8208759](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8208759) and [8126880](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8126880).)

As you point out, the only currently available options seem to be [sorting your cards](https://www.imore.com/wallet#reorder) in an order you can remember or relying on details like a card balance or the last four digits of a card number.

On the other hand, if it's important enough to warrant the trouble (not to mention the awkwardness), you could perhaps [create your own dummy cards](https://www.howtogeek.com/286620/how-to-add-any-card-to-the-iphone-wallet-app-even-if-it-isnt-supported-by-apple/) and use them as labels, naming each for a card you want to identify and sorting it above the card it refers to.

You can request a feature at https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html.